# Most efficient way to insert line of bool values to raw array

Tags: c++, arrays, input

In my program on input i do get different length line of bool values(i know the  length of line) from standard input, for example:

```
"1 0 0 1 0 0 1"
```

This line will be inserted to bool array, in this example:

```
bool tab[7];
```

I will be working on big 2Dimensional array and I'm looking for most efficient way to insert this input into array.

Comment: Unless this is for some high frequency trading application, where every nanosecond counts, any simple parsing approach will be "efficient" enough. You just want someone to write the code for you, right?

Comment: Use [`std::bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset)?

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible ways
first of all, you could use std::bitset instead of array (check out documentation if you wish to try this out (this way consumes less memory), since normal bool is actually 8 bits long, not 1 as you might expect
Other way you could use stringstream, load whole input to stringstream, and then just use

```
int counter= 0;
string temp;
while(stringstream >> temp){
    if(temp == "1")
         tab[counter] = true;
    else
         tab[counter] = false;
    counter++;
}
```

to save whole input to array, the way it works is loop will work as long as stringstream still contains something, and space splits things apart in input stream
keep in mind i dont want to provide full code so you can experiment yourself, let me know if you cant figure out how this works

Answer (score 0):

You can do the task the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main() 
{
    char line[] = "1 0 0 1 0 0 1";
    bool tab[7];

    std::istringstream is( line );

    std::fill( std::copy( std::istream_iterator<bool>( is ),
                          std::istream_iterator<bool>(),
                          tab ),
               std::end( tab ), false );

    for ( bool b : tab ) std::cout << std::boolalpha << b << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
true false false true false false true
```

You should do the same in a loop if you have a two-dimensional array of strings.

Answer (score 0):

I've found two almost equally good solutions to the performance problem of standard input (cin).

1. Use `scanf()` which reduced my program execution time from ~10s to ~5s
2. Include `std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);` in code, so cin does not to keep synced with underlying layer of C library